# How do I compile my OCaml code into a standalone bytecode executable?

Tags: ocaml

I want to compile my OCaml project into an executable that can be run in other computers that don't have OCaml installed. Using ocamlbuild, when I compile a ".native" file it works fine on other machines but if I compile a ".byte" file it fails with a `Cannot exec ocamlrun` message when I try to run the executable.

Since the bytecode version of my program is significantly smaller in terms of file size, I would prefer to distribute it instead of the native code. Is there a way to bundle ocamlrun into the executable when I compile it?

Comment: I would say that if you bundle ocamlrun with your bytecode the size of your program will be comparable to or larger than the native version. Am I right?

Comment: @AnthonyScemama: yeah, thats what ended up happening :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to compile in a custom mode, from ocamlc user [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual022.html):

> -custom
>
> Link in “custom runtime” mode. In the default linking mode, the linker produces bytecode that is intended to be executed with the
> shared runtime system, ocamlrun. In the custom runtime mode, the
> linker produces an output file that contains both the runtime system
> and the bytecode for the program. The resulting file is larger, but it
> can be executed directly, even if the ocamlrun command is not
> installed. Moreover, the “custom runtime” mode enables static linking
> of OCaml code with user-defined C functions, as described in chapter
>
> Unix:   Never use the strip command on executables produced by ocamlc -custom, this would remove the bytecode part of the executable.

If you're using `oasis` then all that you need is to add `Custom : true` field to your executable section, similarly, for `ocamlbuild`, add `-tag custom` or put custom in `_tags` .

Comment: similarly, for ocamlbuild, add `-tag custom` or put custom in `_tags`

Comment: thanks for the note, and don't afraid just to edit the answer, SO is a collaboration tool.